# Удалить текст после </data> используя регулярные выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x

Допустим есть **xml** файл

```
    <data>
        <items>
            <item name="item1"></item>
            <item name="item2"></item>
            <item name="item3"></item>
            <item name="item4"></item>
        </items>
    </data>

AAA BBB CCC
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно с помощю регулярных выражений удалить все что после `</data>`, Тоесть **AAA BB...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эту задачу можно и без регулярных решить:

```py
text = """
    <data>
        <items>
            <item name="item1"></item>
            <item name="item2"></item>
            <item name="item3"></item>
            <item name="item4"></item>
        </items>
    </data>

AAA BBB CCC
"""

try:
    i = text.rindex('</data>')
    text = text[: i + len('</data>')]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Но если очень хочется, то:

```py
import re
text = re.sub(r'(</data>).+', r'\1', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(text)
```

Comment: Спасибо! работает, если можно подскажи, приходит строкой, как можно удалить через re символ **b**

```b'<?xml version="1.0"```

Comment: `b'`? Похоже, вы печатаете в консоль не строку, а байтовое представление строки. Если проведете его декодирование, получите строку: `b'<?xml version="'.decode()` В `decode` можно передавать кодировку, по умолчанию используется `utf-8`. Но... если через re: `re.sub(r'^b(.+)', r'\1', '''b'<?xml version="1.0"''')`. Вообще, использовать re чтобы удалить первый символ очень мощно, ведь можно просто: `'''b'<?xml version="1.0"'''[1:]` т.е. возвращаем всю строку после первого символа

Comment: @gil9red кодировка xml может быть другой указана (не utf-8), поэтому `.decode()` (без аргумента использующий sys.getdefaultencoding()==utf-8) может породить кракозябры (из-за использования несовместимой кодировки)¶ Если прямо внутри строки автор видит `b'..'` (а не в выводе), то что-то сломано выше по течению (следует это исправить). decode() никак не поможет в этом случае. В худшем случае, может ast.literal_eval() понадобиться, если ввод нельзя изменить выше.

Comment: ок, приходит вот такое в начале, это уже в консоле b' проверяю какой тип, выводит str. пробую парснуть etree.fromstring(xml) выбивает что не может спарсить файл ошибка типо не стартует с этого символа '<', ок забрал. И теперь ошибка **ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.**

Comment: @Maic, как jfs писал, проблемой может что-то выше в коде. Если вы не можете справиться,то создайте новый вопрос с проблемой. В вопросе приведите код и текст ошибки, включая стек